# Get QID from Wikidata label name, via SPARQL

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I use api.php to get the QID of something using its English label.
Example: `Mozambique` → `Q1029`

```
$ wget --quiet -O - "http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities \
  &sites=enwiki&titles=Mozambique&format=xml&props="

<?xml version="1.0"?><api success="1"><entities><entity id="Q1029" type="item" /></entities></api>
```

**QUESTION**: How to do the same with a single small SPARQL request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it isn't short:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE{  
  ?item ?label "Mozambique"@en.  
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 .
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
```

You can see it [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Mozambique%22%40en.%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%09%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D).

Comment: This worked, but when I searched for "I Robot", I got back the 1977 progressive rock album and no way to disambiguate.